# Using GKE service account credentials with kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to invoke kubectl from within my CI system. I wish to use a google cloud service account for authentication. I have a secret management system in place that injects secrets into my CI system.

However, my CI system does not have gcloud installed, and I do not wish to install that. It only contains kubectl. Is there any way that I can use a credentials.json file containing a gcloud service account (not a kubernetes service account) directly with kubectl?

Comment: Maybe u just need to extract the credentials from gcloud json file into kubeconfig format and use it with kubectl

Comment: or just create a service account and use it with kubectl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to skip the gcloud CLI is to probably use the [`--token`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#option-2-use-the-token-option) option. You can get a token with RBAC by creating a service account and tying it to a [`ClusterRole` or `Role`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole) with either a [`ClusterRoleBinding` or `RoleBinding`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole).

Then from the command line:

```
$ kubectl --token <token-from-your-service-account> get pods
```

You still will need a `context` in your `~/.kube/config`:

```
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
  name: kubernetes-token
```

Otherwise, you will have to use:

```
$ kubectl --insecure-skip-tls-verify --token <token-from-your-service-account> -s https://<address-of-your-kube-api-server>:6443 get pods
```

Note that if you don't want the token to show up on the logs you can do something like this:

```
$ kubectl --token $(cat /path/to/a/file/where/the/token/is/stored) get pods
```

Also, note that this doesn't prevent you from someone running `ps -Af` on your box and grabbing the token from there, for the lifetime of the `kubectl` process (It's a good idea to rotate the tokens)

Edit:

You can use the [`--token-auth-file=/path/to/a/file/where/the/token/is/stored`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#static-token-file) with `kubectl` to avoid passing it through `$(cat /path/to/a/file/where/the/token/is/stored)`

Comment: How do I get a token for my service account if I'm outside the cluster?

Comment: You can do `kubectl describe sa` then get the token name associated with it, and then `kubectl describe secret <token-name>`