# Get a kubectl client key and cert when using GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am writing a Go binary that will run on my local machine. I wish to authenticate with the kubernetes API for a GKE cluster. How can I get a client key and certificate?

(Note that a kubernetes service account does not seem appropriate because my binary does not itself run on the cluster. And I do not want to have to install gcloud locally because I may want to distribute my binary to others, so I cannot use the gcloud auth helper flow.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get it from GKE because GCP doesn't expose the CA key for you to create client certificate/key pairs for you to authenticate with the cluster. That key lives in the Kubernetes master(s) and GKE doesn't give you direct access to them (They manage them). I recommend you use a [token](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#static-token-file).

Check my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53182585/2989261) with more details. Basically, create a ServiceAccount and bind it to a Role or ClusterRole (RBAC). You can actually authenticate outside your cluster using a token tied to a ServiceAccount.

Comment: I was having big trouble setting up client cert auth with AKS, using getting client cert signed by AKS + using token for SA totally saved the day. thanks